# How can I delete a file with the name "*"?

Tags: filenames, rm

Someone who isn't me ran `dd if=/dev/zero of=* iflag=fullblock,count_bytes count=200G`, so now there's a 200gb file taking up space on my filesystem. Is there a way to delete it without running `rm *` ?

Comment: It would seem that just adding double-quotes do the trick `rm "*"`. But be careful, I just tested this, it's not my amazing knowledge :)

Answer (score 4):

Below I create and then delete a file named "*".  The "\" is often called an "escape" by Unix guys as it tells bash to not interpret the next character, use it literally.

```
[ahill@infprd-sftp01 ~]$ ls -l
total 0
[ahill@infprd-sftp01 ~]$ touch test1
[ahill@infprd-sftp01 ~]$ touch \*
[ahill@infprd-sftp01 ~]$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ahill ahill 0 Sep 20 16:28 *
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ahill ahill 0 Sep 20 16:28 test1
[ahill@infprd-sftp01 ~]$ rm \*
[ahill@infprd-sftp01 ~]$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ahill ahill 0 Sep 20 16:28 test1
```

Comment: any of `"*"`, `'*'` or `\*` work

Comment: I am surprised that double quotes work as a variable in double quotes expands... but OK.  I like the escape best still as visually, it says to me 'This character right here will be used literally.'  Maybe not a big deal in this example, but in a longer string it would put my mind at ease.

Comment: expands, yes, but doesn't get word-split or used as filename glob. The things that are special in double quotes are dollar signs, backticks, and backslashes.

Comment: Bash’s manual calls the forms @ilkkachu mentioned quote characters (this includes backslashes). I think of it like lisp quotes